# URL mapping IIS

Tags: webserver, iis-8, url-rewrite-module, plex

I'm in my home network trying to set some things up.
I have a IIS server running which handles multiple websites. In my router, all traffic coming in at port 80 are sent to that server.

Now I have another machine running a plex-server which is by default on port 32400. I would like configure my set-up so I can surf to plex.mydomain.com on port 80 and I get my plex server.

I've managed to make a revers proxy rule in IIS which rewrites my url to plex.mydomain.com:32400/web/{R:1}.
I'm able to surf to plex.mydomain.com now, but my url is changing to plex.mydomain.com/web/index.html without the port 32400. Also I do not want to change my public URL, only my internal.

For example: if I'm in a place which blocks trafic on port 32400, I still want to access my plex. that was why I wanted to get in on port 80 in the first place.
So I want to surf to plex.mydomain.com and IIS should translate this to plex.mydomain.com:32400/web/index.html. But I need to stay on port 80 external my network.
Can someone point me into the right direction? I've been trying this for several days now without any success so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ARR https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/planning-for-arr/using-the-application-request-routing-module

Comment: Dear Lex, Thanks for your quick answer. I have been trying to use ARR earlier today, but did not succeed. Could you be a bit more specific on how I could accomplish it? thx!